# Android: POST request, show specific text

Tags: java, android, json

Ok, I'm new to the concept of POST and GET request etc. So I apologize If this is a stupid question.

I have this Async Task in this TvrdjavaFragment.java that gets and shows EVERYTHING from the JSON object as a comment (toast). 
I need to only the *temperatura* for example and show it as a comment, not everything.
My question is **how do I get something specific from a JSON object** ?

This is my TvrdjavaFragment.java file:

```
public class TvrdjavaFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnIdinaperiod;
    TextView pokaziServer;
    String rezultat = "";
    String strURL = "http://MYLINK";

    public TvrdjavaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tvrdjava, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        pokaziServer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testServer);
        //int i = Integer.parseInt(pokaziServer.getText().toString());

        //Log.d("TAG", "TestLogIvan");
        new NabaviServer().execute();

        btnIdinaperiod = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIdinaperiod);

        btnIdinaperiod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PeriodFragment periodFragment = new PeriodFragment();
                FragmentTransaction periodFragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                periodFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, periodFragment);
                periodFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //Kada pretisne BACK, vrati se nazad
                periodFragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public class NabaviServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //super.onPostExecute(s);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("IVANTAG", rezultat);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try{
                URL url = new URL(strURL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.connect();

                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); //??s

                String value = bf.readLine();
                System.out.println("test " + value);
                rezultat = value;


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is how my JSON Object looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "vPritisak": "1",
    "vVazduha": "0",
    "nVisina": "0",
    "temperatura": "0",
    "metan": "0",
    "uDioksid": "1",
    "lokacija": "Kicevo",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "vPritisak": "0",
    "vVazduha": "2",
    "nVisina": "0",
    "temperatura": "0",
    "metan": "0",
    "uDioksid": "0",
    "lokacija": "Cair",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
etc...
```

**EDIT**:
When I try to add JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);, I just get the error " Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException " . 
When I try to add Try - Catch (Like it suggests), the app crashes:

```
       @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);
            String temperatura = jObj.getString("temperatura");//get ur temperatura here

            //try to toast it out,to see the value
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + temperatura,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("IVANTAG", rezultat);
    }
```

Comment: Look for GSON lib it is what you should use.

Comment: You need to parse the Json..to get the value

Answer (score 1):

Your response is JSONArray

```
JSONArray array_data = new JSONArray(value);
JSONObject object_data = array_data.getJSONObject(0); // 0, 1, 2 index of array
```

Than you can get any data from your object

```
object_data.getString("temperatura");
```

Comment: First I get an error _Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException_, then I add Try - Catch , like it suggest and still nothing, look: http://imgur.com/a/q1EQ6

Comment: @IkePr, write your codes inside try catch block
`try {
   ....
   ....
} catch (JSONException e) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse server response which is a JSON formatted string, you can do it like this (in your `onPostExecute`method):

```
try {
    JSONArray serverResponseArray = new JSONArray(yourServerResponseString); 
    // looping through all items of array
    for (int i = 0; i < serverResponseArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject item = serverResponseArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String temperatura = item.getString("temperatura");
        // Now you can do what you want with temperatura (Toast, log...)
        ...
    }
}
catch(JSONException e) {
    // Do something of input string is in fact not JSON well-formed or if specified key does not exist in JSON
}
```

Comment: I get this error at new JSONObject(s) - Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException . When I add the try - catch, the app just crashes when I launch it.

Comment: @IkePr I have updated my answer to catch error if JSON is malformed or if query key doesn't exist (aka `JSONException`)

Answer (score 0):

At your `onPostExecute` you need to parse Json object and store it to a value

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     //super.onPostExecute(s);
 try{
     JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(s);
     String temperatura = jObj.getString("temperatura");//get ur temperatura here

      //if you want,you can get other value as well,example
      String nVisina = jObj.getString("nVisina"); //etc.....

      //do whatever you like here to process your String value

    //try to toast it out,to see the value
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + temperatura,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }catch(JSONException e){
   //Json error,do something here,normally will handle like this
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
}
```

The reason why your app crash because you try to `Toast` outside the `try/catch` block..

```
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("IVANTAG", rezultat);
   //u make this line outside the `try` block
```

Comment: I get this error at new JSONObject(s) - Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException . When I add the try - catch, the app just crashes when I launch it.

Comment: I updated my answer,try to run this in ur `onPostExecute` section,it should be no problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
//JSON from String to Object
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
```

Where but make jsonInString = your response.
More about jackson here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core

This is the dependency, altho' I'm not sure if this is enough, but you can check their github to see how exactly it works:

`compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
    )`